# IdP-Initiated Web SSO Profile using JAVA and SAML 2.0

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

In our web application we act as Identity provider (IdP) which  authenticate users through a Login screen with username/password. On successful authentiocation we would like to display a list of hyperlinks which end-users can click to visit partner (service prodicer) web sites. We plan to accomplish these using SAML 2.0 and HTTP POST binding

The  message will be placed within an HTML FORM as a hidden form control named SAMLResponse as shown below

...

as i am newbie to implementation of SAMLResponse as hidden element in JAVA JSP Links, i have following queries
 - How to generate SAMLResponse object in JAVA and then make it as hidden field - Please point me to examples
- How to Digitally Sign the SAMLResponse in JAVA 
- How to encrypt SAMLResponse in JAVA

Is there a equivalent method in the Java world? Are there out of the box solutions and/or tutorials for common servlet containers or application servers?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at Shibboleth from http://shibboleth.internet2.edu/, an open source IdP and SP implementation. I found it quite mature, even though the whole SAML stuff is not completely trivial to set up.  Once it is working, however, it seems to work just fine. IMHO using a proven implementation is a better idea in security critical contexts than rolling your own with a weak understanding of all the details. This makes your own implementation much more error prone and therefore susceptible to vulnerabilities.

In any case, you can at least look at the IdP component's source code to get hints on how to do certain things, should you still decide to roll your own implementation.

http://svn.middleware.georgetown.edu/view/java-idp/branches/REL_2/src/main/java/edu/internet2/middleware/shibboleth/idp/

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Just want to clarify that we are not looking for full-blown SAML solution all we plan to do is embed SAMLResponse as Hidden Field in HTML Form and do HTTP-POST when our users click on the link. so it boils down to - How to Create SAML Response in JAVA - How to Digitally Sign SAMl Response in JAVA and How to Encrypt SAMl Response in JAVA (we plan to use PGP) but not sure what to use for Digital Signing.

Comment: Sure. I added the link to the source repository to my answer. It takes you directly to the IdP part. You should find good examples in there.